# New roofing job has split the tongue and groove boards that shingles are nailed to -- should I be worried?

Tags: roofing

Our 1956 ranch style has tongue and groove boards on the roof that the new shingles are nailed to.  We did not notice ANY splitting on these boards with the old roof.  Now they are absolutely riddled with horizontal splits.  Should I be worried about this?  The contractor said we needed NO new wood, but the way these boards look now seems ominous to us--like the nails will pull out or something else will go wrong because the boards are so broken up.  Is this going to be a problem, or are we overly concerned?

Comment: It would help to see a picture of the split boards to help us determine the extent and severity.

Comment: It would also be beneficial to know the exact composition of the roof structure, like thickness of the T&G decking, is there plywood on top of the decking, etc.

Comment: We posted an edit 7/15 saying T&G 3/4" thick, no plywood, how to send a picture?  Thanks!